# Boost C++ Singleton error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static long Nsp::HL::flag" (?flag@HL@Nsp@@0JA)

Tags: c++, boost, singleton

I try to create a multi-threaded singleton pattern class.

Header:

```
class HL{

    public:
        static HL* getInstance();
    .........
    private:
        static HL* instance;
        static boost::once_flag flag;
        HL();
        static void initOnce();
}
```

CPP:

```
HL* HL::instance = NULL;

HL* HL::getInstance(){
    if(instance == NULL){
        boost::call_once(flag, initOnce);
    }
    return instance;
}

void HL::initOnce(){
    instance = new HL();
}
```

I get this error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static long Nsp::HL::flag" (?flag@HL@Nsp@@0JA)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to *define* the static member variable in the cpp file:

```
boost::once_flag Nsp::HL::flag;
```

You can initialize it if you need to (I've not used `boost::once_flag`, and can't tell you whether or how it needs to be initialized):

```
boost::once_flag Nsp::HL::flag = {whatever goes here};
```

Comment: Thank you! It works.


`boost::once_flag HL::flag = BOOST_ONCE_INIT;`